# How to divide numbers without remainder in PHP?

Tags: php, math, division

How does one divide numbers but exclude the remainder in PHP?

Comment: Kartik: 13 / 2 = 6 remainder 1, because two goes into thirteen six times evenly, leaving a total of one left, which is the remainder.

Comment: Kartik was making a joke about how the requester misspelled remainder.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Just cast the resulting value to an int.

```
$n = (int) ($i / $m);
```

Interesting functions (depending on what you want to achieve and if you expect negative integers to get devided) are [`floor()`](http://php.net/floor), [`ceil()`](http://php.net/ceil) and [`round()`](http://php.net/round).

Comment: This is, strictly speaking, a bad idea. While it will work well for small values (including all 32bit ints), floats can't represent all 64bit integers. If `$i` is 2^54+2 and `$m` is 2, the result of the division can't be 2^53+1, as that is not representable as a double-precision float (I can't test what the actual result on a 64bit system would be right now).

Answer (score 32):

PHP 7 has a new built-in function for this named `intdiv`.

Example:

```
$result = intdiv(13, 2);
```

The value of `$result` in this example will be `6`.

You can find the full documentation for this function in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php).

Answer (score 8):

For most practical purposes, the accepted answer is correct.

However, for builds where integers are 64 bits wide, not all possible integer values are representable as a double-precision float; See my comment on the accepted answer for details.

A variation of

```
$n = ($i - $i % $m) / $m;
```

(code taken from KingCrunch's comment under another answer) will avoid this problem depending on the desired rounding behavior (bear in mind that the result of the modulus operator may be negative).

Answer (score 0):

or you could just do intval(13 / 2)
gives 6

Answer (score 0):

In addition to decisions above like `$result = intval($a / $b)` there is one particular case:

If you need an integer division (without remainder) by some power of two (`$b` is `2 ^ N`) you can use bitwise right shift operation:

```
$result = $a >> $N;
```

where $N is number from 1 to 32 on 32-bit operating system or 64 for 64-bit ones.

Sometimes it's useful because it's fastest decision for case of $b is some power of two.

And there's a backward *(be careful due to overflow!)* operation for multiplying by power of two:

```
$result = $a << $N;
```

Hope this helps for someone too.

Answer (score -8):

use modulo in php:

```
$n = $i % $m;
```

Comment: -1 - Not only does this not answer the question, it provides what the question specifically asked to omit: the remainder.

Comment: For those who like overkill: It _can_ work with module `$n = ($i - $i % $m) / $m;` :D